# Angular JS - Including Routes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

Is it possible to include a route with angularJs instead of include a html file?

This code works fine

```
<section data-ng-include=" 'views/app/content/dashboard.html' " class="main-container" ></section>
```

But would it be possible to just include the route /dashboard which is already included in my app.js as part of my route provider?

Comment: Sounds like you need ngView?

Comment: thanks dfsq, i was looking and searching the angularjs documentation but couldnt find this. Sorry for the angular js noob question

Answer (score 0):

Answer by dfsq - ngView was required